# MS Access SQL Query - Joining 3 Tables to receive Total Order Price

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to know the total price for a specific order ID. The information is contained in these tables:

Order_line_t

```
Order_ID    Product_ID    Quantity
--------    ----------    --------
1006        4             1
1006        5             2
1006        7             2
```

Uses_t

```
Product_ID    Material_ID    Footage
----------    -----------    -------
4             16             20
5             15             13
7             10             16
```

Raw_Materials_t

```
Material_ID    Unit_Price
-----------    ----------
16             05.70
15             16.72
10             15.55
```

The total cost is computed by

```
Multiplying SUM ( Order_line_t.Quantity * Uses_t.Footage * Raw_Materials_t.Unit_Price) AS Total
```

My current query only returns an error:

```
SELECT Order_line_t.Order_ID, Order_line_t.Product_ID, Uses_t.Product_ID   ,Uses_t.Footage , 
SUM ( Order_line_t.Quantity * Uses_t.Footage * Raw_Materials_t.Unit_Price) AS Total
FROM Order_line_t, Uses_t , Raw_Materials_t
WHERE  Order_line_t.Order_ID = 1006;
```

Help appreciated! How exactly do I JOIN these tables? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you were missing the actual joins between the tables, and secondly you were missing your group by

```
SELECT  Order_line_t.Order_ID, 
            Order_line_t.Product_ID, 
            Uses_t.Product_ID   ,
            Uses_t.Footage , 
            SUM ( Order_line_t.Quantity * Uses_t.Footage * Raw_Materials_t.Unit_Price) AS Total
FROM    Order_line_t  INNER JOIN
            Uses_t  ON  Order_line_t.Product_ID = Uses_t.Product_ID INNER JOIN
            Raw_Materials_t     ON  Uses_t.Material_ID = Raw_Materials_t.Material_ID
WHERE   Order_line_t.Order_ID = 1006;
    GROUP BY Order_line_t.Order_ID, 
            Order_line_t.Product_ID, 
            Uses_t.Product_ID   ,
            Uses_t.Footage
```

**EDIT**

Try this

```
SELECT  Order_line_t.Order_ID, 
        Order_line_t.Product_ID, 
        Uses_t.Product_ID, 
        Uses_t.Footage, 
        Sum([Order_line_t].[Quantity]*[Uses_t].[Footage]*[Raw_Materials_t].[Unit_Price]) AS Total
FROM    (Order_line_t INNER JOIN 
        Uses_t ON Order_line_t.Product_ID = Uses_t.Product_ID) INNER JOIN 
        Raw_Materials_t ON Uses_t.Material_ID = Raw_Materials_t.Material_ID
GROUP BY    Order_line_t.Order_ID, 
            Order_line_t.Product_ID, 
            Uses_t.Product_ID, 
            Uses_t.Footage;
```

**EDIT**

Total by ORDER ID

```
SELECT  Order_line_t.Order_ID,
        Sum([Order_line_t].[Quantity]*[Uses_t].[Footage]*[Raw_Materials_t].[Unit_Price]) AS Total
FROM    (Order_line_t INNER JOIN 
        Uses_t ON Order_line_t.Product_ID = Uses_t.Product_ID) INNER JOIN 
        Raw_Materials_t ON Uses_t.Material_ID = Raw_Materials_t.Material_ID
GROUP BY    Order_line_t.Order_ID;
```

Comment: OK, I will have a look for you quickly

Comment: This looks better! It's working too! However, now I am getting 3 Rows that show the total for each product. But I need just 1 row with Order_ID and Total.

Comment: OK, will change that for you too

Comment: Thank you sir! You are amazing! With this, i should be able to solve the remaining queries! Thanks and have a good night/day!

Comment: @astander, did you see a syntax error also?  I noticed in your first edit, you wrapped your first inner join in parentheses, does Access throw an error if you don't?  I did not actually test my code sample.

Comment: @ExactaBox, yes, yo put it bluntly, access is full of sh!t. You actually have to wrap the joins like that. Give it a test when you have a chance. I am more use to SQL Server, that is why I had to change the original post.

Comment: @all, it wouldn't work without the parenthesis? Thanks again to both of you

Comment: lol, thanks, yes I am much more used to SQL Server syntax as well, which obviously can handle multiple joins without parentheses.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compute the cost for each row, then sum the entire order.  Something like:

```
select 
    Order_ID, sum(RowCost) as OrderCost

from (

    select
        o.Order_ID, o.Product_ID, o.Quantity,
        u.Material_ID, u.Footage,
        r.Unit_Price,
        (o.Quantity * u.Footage * r.UnitPrice) as RowCost

    from
        order_line_t o INNER JOIN
        uses_t u on o.Product_ID = u.Product_ID INNER JOIN
        Raw_materials_t r on u.Material_ID = r.Material_ID

    where
        o.Order_ID = 1006

    ) z

group by
    Order_ID
```